# How to convert .index extension into .idx

Tags: database, text, encoding

I have file with .index extension but I needed .idx file, so is there a way to convert it?

Please help me achieve my goal

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Renaming a file is a trivial exercise. Now I would guess that those are two different data formats, aren't they?